# Owin .AspNet.Correlation.*cookie not found issues

Tags: owin, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using .net. 4.5.2 and latest version on Identity in my application.
There are cases I get strange error from external login  ".AspNet.Correlation.Google cookie not found."

In the logs I see the the I see the url "/signin-google?state=STATE FROM GOOGLE (I got it)" but "AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync" returns NULL and my logs showing the error I mentioned.
This is my configurations:

```
var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType =  DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = ".myApp",
            CookieDomain = ".myApp.com"
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            SlidingExpiration = false,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignOut = (context) =>
                {
                    //remove user cache
                },
                OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                {
                    //add token to claims

                },

                OnException = (context) =>
                {
                    //prevent exception display
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User, int>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(IdentityExpiresIn),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                    {
                        var identity = manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                            DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                        return identity;
                    },
                    getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
            }
        };

     app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
     app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

     var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = AppSettings.Get<string>("GoogleAppID"),
            ClientSecret = AppSettings.Get<string>("GoogleAppSecret"),
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,

        };

        googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email,profile");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

The issue happens usually when using mobile devices and Chrome (cookies are supported) and also with **Facebook connect**

Comment: update the packages and add packages that are related to google,Microsoft and others

Comment: The packages are updated to latest version

Comment: I noticed that this issue happening mostly on mobile devices

Comment: I've had this happen to me in my most recent implementation of a lightweight oauth2 middleware.  It will work fine, for a time, then all of a sudden the correlation cookie will fail to validate.  When it is working, that cookie doesn't show up in the chrome:developer tools:resources:cookies area but when it fails, the aspnet.correlation cookie persists, thus not validating and the login fails.  I have not found the reason for this yet but I have found a few posts about it.

Comment: take a look at this, as it appears that it may be an actual bug in OWIN.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878604/multiple-cookies-issue-in-owin-security-authenticationhandler

Comment: I hope that they will fix it :)